# How to match a string contain specific text preceded by any combination of alphanumerics and other charcters in regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to match strings which have a specific text in start but after that any combination of alphanumeric and character value and string ends with double quotes **"**. Here is the sample string

```
fixed_words_/abcd123/"
```

in this string, **fixed_words_** will always be same and in the end will be **"** but in between there can be digits, alphabets, underscores and slashes.

I tried **mystring.match(/fixed_words_\w*"/g)** but its not working. I am sorry but I am new to regex so don't mind if its a stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `\w`, have a character class that can match either `\w` (alphanumerics/underscores) or a slash:

```
mystring.match(/fixed_words_[\/\w]*"/g)
```

The above assumes that your expression can appear anywhere (or multiple times!) in `mystring`.  If you want `mystring` to contain *only* your expression, add a start-of-string anchor (`^`) at the beginning, an end-of-string anchor (`$`) at the end, and get rid of the `g` flag permitting multiple matches:

```
mystring.match(/^fixed_words_[\/\w]*"$/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex to match your string: **^\s*fixed_words_[^"]"\s*$**

[^"]* will match all the characters until it finds a double quote (**"**) character.